# Varnish ESI & Wordpress - simulate loading a post

Tags: php, wordpress, varnish, esi

**Update: I've answered this myself. See below.**

I guess I'm asking for the equivalent of a `set_the_id()` function, if one existed.

I'm using Wordpress with Varnish for performance, and I want to use an ESI (Edge Side Include) for the sidebar, so things like recent/popular posts can be refreshed more frequently than the post content itself.

[One way of doing this](http://timbroder.com/2012/12/getting-started-with-varnish-edge-side-includes-and-wordpress.html) is creating an endpoint in your plugins directory etc. for Varnish to access from an ESI comment, with some code like this:

```
<?php
/* ESI handler for Varnish - Sidebar (all tabs except search) */

$cwd = getcwd();
$path = substr($cwd, 0, strpos($cwd, 'wp-content/'));
require $path . 'wp-blog-header.php';


    echo '<!-- ESI sidebar created '.date(DATE_RFC2822).' -->',"\n";
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' ) )
    {
        echo '<!-- Unable to load primary-widget-area (sidebar) -->';
    }
?>
```

All fine so far; this is enough to load Wordpress and it to find all the relevant plugins.  However they produce errors at various points (specifically `wp-includes/post-template.php` line 29) because they need to use things like [get_the_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID), [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) and properties of the post object to highlight certain posts and so on and no post has been loaded yet.

How can I tell Wordpress to load a specific post ID in the code above, as if I'd gone to a URL like `http://example.com?p=1`, but without outputting a full page?  I just want the environment to be setup as if post was active, then I can pass the current post ID as a parameter in my ESI call.

I thought [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) might help and I tried adding:

```
query_posts( 'p=5' );
```

but it doesn't do anything.

I also wondered about `WP_Post::get_instance()` (it only seems to take an object though, not a post ID).

Is there anything else I can use?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=1' );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();   // this loads it
}
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query for all the other parameters.